# A sum of typedLit columns evaluates to NULL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a sum column by taking the sum of the row values of a set of columns in a dataframe. So I followed the following method to do it.

```
val temp_data = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1, 5),
  (2, 4),
  (3, 7),
  (4, 6)
)).toDF("A", "B")

val cols  = List(col("A"), col("B"))
temp_data.withColumn("sum", cols.reduce(_ + _)).show
```

```
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|sum|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  5|  6|
|  2|  4|  6|
|  3|  7| 10|
|  4|  6| 10|
+---+---+---+
```

So this methods works fine and produce the expected output. However, I want to create the cols variable without specifying the column names explicitly. Therefore I've used typedLit as follows.

```
val cols2 = temp_data.columns.map(x=>typedLit(x)).toList
```

when I look at `cols` and `cols2` they look identical.

```
cols: List[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = List(A, B)
cols2: List[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = List(A, B)
```

However, when I use `cols2` to create my sum column, it doesn't work the way I expect it to work.

```
temp_data.withColumn("sum", cols2.reduce(_ + _)).show
```

```
+---+---+----+
|  A|  B| sum|
+---+---+----+
|  1|  5|null|
|  2|  4|null|
|  3|  7|null|
|  4|  6|null|
+---+---+----+
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Why doesn't the second method work like the first method?

Answer (score 2):

`lit` or `typedLit` is not a replacement for `Column`. What your code does it creates a list of string  literals - `"A"` and `"B"`

```
temp_data.select(cols2: _*).show
```

```
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
|  A|  B|
|  A|  B|
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
```

and asks for their sums - hence the result is undefined.

You might use `TypedColumn` here:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn

val typedSum: TypedColumn[Any, Int] = cols.map(_.as[Int]).reduce{ 
  (x, y) => (x + y).as[Int]
}

temp_data.withColumn("sum", typedSum).show
```

but it doesn't provide any practical advantage over standard `Column` here.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying with typedLit which is not right and like other answer mentioned you don't have to use a function with TypedColumn. You can simply use map transformation on columns of dataframe to convert it to List(Col)

Change your cols2 statement to below and try.

```
val cols  = temp_data.columns.map(f=> col(f))
temp_data.withColumn("sum", cols.reduce(_ + _)).show
```

You will get below output.

```
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|sum|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  5|  6|
|  2|  4|  6|
|  3|  7| 10|
|  4|  6| 10|
+---+---+---+
```

Thanks